# Why do I get heap buffer overflow in leetcode?

Tags: arrays, c, if-statement, heap-memory, palindrome

I was trying to solve a problem for returning the longest palindrome in a string.
I first copy the string in reverse order, and then try to find the longest substring.
Here is the code I wrote:

```
char *longestPalindrome(char *s) {
    int len = strlen(s);
    char c[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        c[i] = s[len - 1 - i];
    }
    int st = 0;
    int length = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            int l = 0;
            for (int k = 0; ((i + k) < len) && ((j + k) < len); k++) {
                if (s[i + k] == c[j + k])
                    l++;
                else
                    break;
            }
            if (l > length) {
                length = l;
                st = i;
            }
        }
    }
    char *ans = (char *)calloc(length, sizeof(char));
    for (int i = 0; (i < length) && (i + st < len); i++) {
        ans[i] = s[i + st];
    }
    return ans;  
}
```

I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000000033
  at pc 0x559567cee1ab bp 0x7ffdab22ea70 sp 0x7ffdab22ea60
```

Now, when I comment out the `if`-`else` conditions inside the third `for` loop, I do not get any error. Why does this happen?
In spite of adding the conditions `(i + k) < len` and `(j + k) < len`?

I tried commenting out the `if`-`else` condition and the code gives no error.

Comment: Do you remember that a string in C is really called a *null-terminated* string? If you want a character array to be used as a string, you need to make sure that it's null-terminated, and that you allocate space for the null-terminator.

Comment: Also, create a [mre] that you can build (with many extra warnings enabled, and with sanitizers) locally. Then you can easily [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) it yourself to see what happens.

Comment: Use your debugger and analyse the situation when the error occurs.

Comment: I'll try compiling and debugging with "-wall" and also see about the '\0' case. Thanks for the suggestions : )

Comment: Side-note: Don't cast the result of `malloc()` and family. These memory allocation functions return a generic `void *` that is implicitly converted to any other pointer such. Casting is redundant and merely serves to clutter one's code.

Comment: Are you sure the error message comes from the posted code? I don't think so.

Comment: That option should be `-Wall`. And you should also add `-Wextra -pedantic`

Comment: @Gerhardh Assuming that the "real" code includes `stdlib.h` there will be no warnings for this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- you must allocate one extra byte for the match and store a null terminator at the end of the block to make it a proper C string:

  ```
    char *ans = calloc(length + 1, sizeof(char));
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        ans[i] = s[st + i];
    }
    ans[length] = '\0';
    return ans;
  ```

  note that you could also use `strndup()` and replace the whole code block with

  ```
    return strndup(st + i, length);
  ```

  without a null terminator, the calling code will cause an out of bounds access as it tries to locate the end of the string, for example when printing it.
- The algorithm does not find embedded palindromes in the argument string, it finds substrings that happen to have a reversed version embedded somewhere in the argument string. For example for `"a dog has no god"` will return `"dog "`, which is not a palindrome.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *longestPalindrome(const char *s) {
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    size_t st = 0;
    size_t length = 0;
    size_t i, n, k;
    for (i = 0; i + length < len; i++) {
        for (n = length + 1; i + n < len; n++) {
            for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                if (s[i + k] != s[i + n - 1 - k])
                    break;
            }
            if (k == n) {
                /* found a palindrome of length n */
                length = n;
                st = i;
            }
        }
    }
    return strndup(s + st, length);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        char *p = longestPalindrome(argv[i]);
        printf("'%s' -> '%s'\n", argv[i], p);
        free(p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The `strdup` and `strndup` functions have been part of the POSIX Standard for a long time, and they have finally been incorporated into the upcoming C23 standard.  If `strndup()` is not available on your system, it can be written this way:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *strndup(const char *s, size_t n) {
    char *p = malloc(n + 1);
    if (p != NULL) {
        memcpy(p, s, n);
        p[n] = '\0';
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Good answer. AFAIK `strndup` is (still) non-standard. Perhaps worth to mention.

Comment: @SupportUkraine: Good news: POSIX function `strndup` has finally made it into the next C Standard: **C23 7.26.2.7 The `strndup` function**.

Comment: Sounds great. Sorry but I can't upvote twice ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need to terminate your result string before printing it. Just change `calloc(length, ...` to `calloc(length + 1, ...`.

Answer (score 1):

The posted code will not give the error posted in the question. There are no out-of-bounds access in the posted code.

In other words - the error comes from some code that isn't posted. Maybe/likely the caller of `longestPalindrome` uses the returned pointer `ans` in a way that causes the posted error.

The key is here:

> ...returning the longest palindrome **in a string**.

Your code doesn't return a C style string. The allocated memory doesn't contain a string termination character (NUL termination).
(note: currently there isn't even room for the termination in the allocated memory)

So if the `caller` do something like:

```
...
char* str = longestPalindrome(someString);
if (str) puts(str);
```

the `puts` call will access memory out-of-bounds.

Solution: Make sure `ans` points to memory that contains a termination character.

Also the code doesn't handle the case where the input is an empty string. This can also result in errors.

BTW: Be careful about using VLAs like `char c[len];`. If the input string is very big it may result in stack overflow.

Comment: Good point about VLAs

Comment: An interesting side question is: can this problem be solved in linear time?